# Control back button url in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to be able to control history for back button.  If there are any postbacks on a page the back button counts these actions in history but what I want it to do is simply return to the previous page instead.
Is there a method to be able to do this?  I did look into history.replaceState(), would this work?
I did try using the onhashchange event to capture the back button being clicked but seemed to ignore it completely in chrome??

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you need to know about whether you are coding on `HTML5` standards, since history object can be manipulated only in HTML5. Since you are coding `ASP.NET` it is valulale to know are you going to support old versions of IE and by old I mean previous to version 9.

Depending again by `control`, since you cannot control a web browser. Remember that Web is an open platform and user can navigate to wherever she desires to. Capturing the browser back button is not a trivial solution, it is hacky. There are too many browsers each with their click event, my suggestion is that start thinking in web scenario not a .NET application (I am coming from a .NET background myself).

I personally would either go for `pushState` or `replaceState` depending on the case. They are methods implemented across all browsers and will not be tricky to implement them. See this amazing MDN post [Manipulating the Browser History](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) . You can push a new state, create a new state and navigate to a certain point in user's browser experience, really easily and it is part of the HTML standard, so you are not hacking anything as simple as the following code:

```
window.history.back(); // Go back in history
window.history.forward(); //Go forward in history

var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");  //Push your new desired state in URL

var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.replaceState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html"); // Will use the current object
//insteadof creating another one
```

**UPDATE**: In case you want to force navigation to a HTML, just use the pushState or replaceState like the followings:

```
var enforcedPageToVisit = "
var stateObj = { pageName: "test" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "Page to visit evertime when you click back", enforcedPageToVisit);
```

Comment: Imagine a typical asp.net web forms application and a page has had several postbacks.  When clicking back it goes back to the previous action, I just want to be able to ignore these and go back to the previous page instead, will the above help me do this?

Comment: yes, indeed! Updated my answer for your case again.

Comment: I added the code above to Master Page and it made no difference, kept getting usual Confirm Page Submission type messages instead of returning to previous page.

Comment: add more code to question so that I can help. Where did u add the code and what did u expect it to be?